# Sort the nested list by the sublist content; sublists of different lengths

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, sorting

I would like to write the function `NewSort` function that sorts a list of sorted sublists, basing first on the canonical ordering of subsequent sublist elements. In case of the tie, the shorter sublist should be first.

**Example 1:**

```
NewSort[{{1,2,4},{3,4},{1,3}}]
```

Should give

```
{{1,2,4},{1,3},{3,4}}
```

**Example 2:**

```
NewSort[{{1,2,3},{1,2},{1}}]
```

Should give

```
{{1},{1,2},{1,2,3}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edited version:** this is a clean-up by taking into consideration the added example provided in the comments section by the author of the OP.

I am suggesting the following function:

```
foo[l_List] := 
 Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros /@ 
    PadRight /@ 
     SortBy[#, Table[#[[xx]], {xx, 1, Min[Dimensions /@ l]}] &] &@
  PadRight@l
```

Now, we define the four lists; two from the OP, the one I had provided as example 3 and the one in the comments by the author of the OP.

```
list1 = {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 4}, {1, 3}};
list2 = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1}};
list3 = {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {1, 3, 7, 8}, {1, 3}};
list4 = {{1}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 5}};
```

We act with the function

```
foo[list1]
foo[list2]
foo[list3]
foo[list4]
```

> [image: fooall]

**Edit:** thanks to the comment by @E. Chan-López, there's the shorter version:

```
foo[l_List] := 
 DeleteCases[#, 0] & /@ SortBy[#, Min[Length /@ l] &] &@PadRight@l
```

Comment: Although this solves the problem, it is a loop-based solution. Is it possible to find something more efficient?

Comment: @wedelfach by loop, you mean that I used a `Table` in `SortBy`?

Comment: Yes, if I understood Your solution correctly, it run over every sublist on the parent list.

Comment: @wedelfach if you don't run over the lists in the original list, how are you going to sort them? Also, `Table[#[[xx]], {xx, 1, Min[Dimensions /@ l]}]` is because I assumed that we don't know the exact lengths of the sublists.

Comment: You are actually right, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @wedelfach thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure that this works when difference between elements occurs only at position larger than `Min[Dimensions /@ l]}]`. E.g. `foo[{{1}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 5}}]` produces `{{1}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 5}}` while I would expect `{{1}, {1, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 2, 4}}`.

Comment: @wedelfach I cleaned up the answer and wrote it as a single function. Can you please check? Many thanks

Comment: Yes, now it works properly. Thank You again!

Comment: @wedelfach ok, great. Thanks again for checking!

Comment: A bit shorter: `DeleteCases[#, 0] & /@ SortBy[#, Min[Length /@ l] &] &@PadRight@l`

Comment: @E.Chan-López cheers mate. I updated the answer. not sure why I like undocumented stuff so much :-)

Comment: Hi, mate! I like undocumented functions because they have their surprises :-)